# spring-boot 3.0 Discord OAuth2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, discord

I want to make a Discord OAuth2 login for my website.

I found following code for an older Spring version on GitHub https://github.com/fourscouts/blog/tree/master/oauth2-discord
I had to add the SecurityFilterChain in the Configuration because of the new spring version. My Problem now is, that I can acces the Discord login page when I go to http://localhost:8080/login but when I get redirected from Discord I get presented with the error Message you can see in the picture.
[Error after Discord redirect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNkHD.png)
I also get the following message in the console:
`Response 400 BAD_REQUEST No event was found for the exception org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException`
I have no idea what I should try next.
I uploaded my code to github so you can have a look at it: https://github.com/mrmrmystery/somewhatweb

Answer (score 1):

In Spring, I accomplished this with the following configs in my application.properties

```
# OAuth2 Discord Registration
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.discord.provider=discord
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.discord.client-id=CLIENT_ID
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.discord.client-secret=SECRET
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.discord.client-authentication-method=post
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.discord.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.discord.scope[0]=identify
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.discord.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/discord

# OAuth2 Sign-In-With-Discord
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.discord.authorization-uri=https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/authorize
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.discord.token-uri=https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.discord.user-info-uri=https://discordapp.com/api/users/@me
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.discord.user-name-attribute=username
```

[image: Example Image]

Comment: And that configuration was everything needed? With Spring 6 the authorization code retrieval does not contain the client-secret so I get a HTTP 400 from discord.

Answer (score 0):

Could you solve the issue with Discord Login?

It might be the case that you need a

`public class OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler`
while you can use other SuccessHandlers to extend it with.

Then, inside this SuccessHandler,you implement the onAuthenticationSuccess method from the base class.

```java
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
```

Then you can set it in your filterChain like this:

```java
        .oauth2Login(oauth2login -> {
          oauth2login.successHandler(successHandler);
        })
```