# spring-security 6 with discord as Oauth2 identity provider

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, discord

I'm trying to configure discord as identity provider with spring-security 6. As web framework I'm using vaadin. According to [spring-boot 3.0 Discord OAuth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75340860/spring-boot-3-0-discord-oauth2) it should be sufficient to configure the identity provider in application.yaml:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          discord:
            client-id: ${DISCORD_CLIENT_ID}
            client-secret: ${DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET}
            client-authentication-method: 'post'
            authorization-grant-type: 'authorization_code'
            scope: 
            - 'identify'
            - 'guilds'
            - 'email'
            redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/discord"
        provider:
          discord:
            authorization-uri: 'https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/authorize'
            token-uri: 'https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token'
            user-info-uri: 'https://discordapp.com/api/users/@me'
            user-name-attribute: 'username'
```

But using the token endpoint returned HTTP 400 all the time since there has been no authentication sent to it with that configuration. So I created a decorator for DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient to call an interceptor on the used RestTemplate to add the basic auth. And now discord.app/api/oauth2/token returns the tokens (access_token and refresh_token). But spring-security fails in reading the json and returns an empty Oauth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequest instead.

I checked by logging the whole body of the message and the full json with everything needed is in there. Did anyone succeed with spring-security 6 and discord yet?

Comment: I'm not sure if you have any other issues in this config, but you will want to change `client-authentication-method: 'post'` to `client-authentication-method: 'client_secret_post'`. The `post` value is no longer valid in Spring Security 6 / Spring Boot 3. I have recently updated the [Spring Boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/web.html#web.security.oauth2.client) to provide a corrected example. See [#13144](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/13144).

Comment: That information fixed everything. I could remove all the nasty tokenEndpoint stuff and it works now out-of-the-box. Thank you. I'd love to approve the answer, but the solution is "only" a comment. If you don't want to write an answer to be approvied, I'd do it in a few days ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to change `client-authentication-method: 'post'` to `client-authentication-method: 'client_secret_post'`.

The value `post` is no longer valid in Spring Security 6 / Spring Boot 3, as some [deprecated constants and code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/commit/58e32350931100e38265788f1a024bab5b890f5b) were [removed](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/commit/be58e2ac49bb0d4b5996df0f8b830d08e6800571#diff-10f22fdd52ef116c50401d46f8d95362330ff198e55abb1addf731711088cb74).

I have recently [updated](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/35679) the [Spring Boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/web.html#web.security.oauth2.client) to provide a corrected example. Also see Spring Security issue [#13144](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/13144), which we're working on to provide a proactive error message to catch this issue and help developers work past it.